# onchange not working when the page loads until I remove and then add it back to the code

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown which has an onchange event inside the select tag. The onchange should call a function but I have also tested it just requesting an alert()

```
   <select onchange="alert('test')">.......
```

For some reason when I load the page in the browser it does not work but if I remove the onchange from the element code via the browser and then write the onchange request back into the code from the exact place that I removed it, it works. I have even copied the onchange snippet and pasted it back in just to make sure I was using the same syntax and when I paste it back it starts working immediately

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console when you load the page with the `onchange` attribute specified?

Comment: Does work in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4cuh/ - are you sure the error is not something else?

Comment: @Yuck No errors at all in the console.

Comment: @puelo I'm sure it's possible that it could be something else because it does work if write it in through the browser but I can't imagine what it would be.

Comment: Probably better to use an event listener anyway.

Comment: I can't use the option tags as the drop down is being generated through magento's own system. I only have access to the select tag and I'm not aware of anything else that would work. If you could suggest something I would appreciate it though? @isherwood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can be more sure that the click handler is initialized after load by using an event listener, plus you maintain separation of behavior and presentation:

```
window.onload = function() {
    addEvent(document.getElementById('mySelect'), 'change', myChangeFunction);
}
```

That said, there does seem to be something else wrong with your situation.

Comment: Interestingly this only works if I enter your function via the console. Which leaves me in the same position as before but it's not unique to the onchange

Comment: Ok there was another event listening to onchange events in a js file that I hadn't seen. Thanks very much you're answer sent me in the right direction at least